# Small Propellanes Stability

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

Why is [1.1.1] propellane more stable than other small members in the propellane family even though it seems to be under the greatest strain?  What makes a small propellanes stable, or in general, any propellane stable?

Comment: Interesting question. Strangely, Wikipedia contradicts itself here: On the propellanes page it says: `Surprisingly, the most strained member [1.1.1] is far more stable than the other small ring members ([2.1.1], [2.2.1], [2.2.2], [3.2.1], [3.1.1], and [4.1.1]).`,  but on the page for [2.2.2] propellane it says `This ([2.2.2] propellane) compound is unstable (although not as much as [1.1.1]propellane). The bond angles on the shared carbons are considerably strained: three of them are close to 90°, the other three to 120°. The strain energy is estimated to be 93 kcal/mol (390 kJ/mol).`.

Comment: Then what is the general consensus?

Comment: I think [Carey A. F. Advanced Organic Chemistry: Part A: Structure and Mechanisms, 2000, p. 164](https://books.google.ru/books?id=z3jXKOYuqQAC&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=propellane+stability&source=bl&ots=dMepB29-Rm&sig=KdnGRbXJ4KIBUnJh5Huu-nmedkc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=propellane%20stability&f=false) pretty much answers your question.

Comment: @andselisk Can you write an answer for this. The link is not working on my phone.

Comment: @Mockingbird Done, sorry for the inconvenience, that was a link to Google Books which can be wacky sometimes to get access to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fulfilling the request from @Mockingbird, there is a quote from (1, p. 90)

> Surprisingly, [1.1.1]propellane is somewhat more stable to thermal
>   decomposition than the next larger propellane, [2.1.1]propellane,
>   indicating a reversal in the trend of increased reactivity with
>   increased strain. To understand this observation, it is important to
>   recognized that the energy of *both the reactant and intermediate*
>   influence the rate of unimolecular reactions that lead to
>   decomposition. In the case of propellanes, homolytic rupture of the
>   central bond is expected to be the initial step in decomposition. This
>   bond rupture is very endothermic for [1.1.1]propellane. Because
>   relatively less strain is released in the case of [1.1.1]propellane
>   than in the [2.1.1]- and [2.2.1]-homologs, [1.1.1]propellane is
>   kinetically most stable.([2](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.198603121/abstract))
>
> [image]
>
> Another manifestation of the relatively small release of strain
>   associated with breaking the central bond comes from `MP4/6-31G∗`
>   calculations on the energy of the reverse ring closure.([3](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00115a011))
>
> [image]
>
> The thermal decomposition of [1.1.1]propellane has been studied both
>   experimentally and by computation([4](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja994043v))

The book chapter further discusses reactivity of [1.1.1]propellane, if OP is really interested in this area, I would suggest to grab the book in the library or focus on the papers (2-4) the book references to.

(1) Carey, F. A.; Sundberg, R. J. Advanced organic chemistry. Part A. Structure and Mechanisms, 5th ed.; Springer: New York, 2007.
(2) Wiberg, K. B. Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. Engl. 1986, 25 (4), 312–322. [DOI: 10.1002/anie.198603121](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.198603121/abstract)
(3) Adcock, W.; Binmore, G. T.; Krstic, A. R.; Walton, J. C.; Wilkie, J. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 1995, 117 (10), 2758–2766. [DOI: 10.1021/ja00115a011](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00115a011)
(4) Jarosch, O.; Walsh, R.; Szeimies, G. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2000, 122 (35), 8490–8494. [DOI: 10.1021/ja994043v](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja994043v)